# Plotting probabilistic histogram on a specific range on log scale

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms, logarithmic-scale

I'm having a problem getting a combined effect - I have a list of values for which I'd like to plot a histogram. As a minimal example:

```
data={0.00207824,0.0025943,0.0011068,0.00232267,
0.000191364,0.001509,0.000188004,0.000428207,
0.00435273,0.00412084,0.00247925,0.0104363,
0.000592709,0.00265474,0.000869573,0.0201809,
0.000121145,0.000526594,0.000206296,0.000428068,
0.0000799537,0.00748977,0.000390255,0.0000120368,
0.000310765,0.000236278,0.000757155,0.000487673,
0.0032382,0.0171548,0.000727257,0.0027107,
5.816414794263675*10^( -7)}


Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> {0.00001, 1}]
```

The histogram's y-axis should be a probability. Both axes need to be on log-scale. I've solved that, but now I'd like to have the x-axis on a specified range. Apparently once there was HistogramRange which was superceded by PlotRange which gives me nothing.

It's probably silly but I can't find a solution. Anyone knows how?
Thanks in advance.

Update:

Strangely, the following command produces a much nicer log-scale x-axis (by nicer I mean with better resolution to the whole range):

```
Show[Histogram[data, "Log", "Probability"]]
```

I still don't know how to specifically scale the axis.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you could post your code, or at least a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of what you're trying to do, it helps people to understand exactly what you're trying to do and give better feedback.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I edited it. It's not very aesthetic but it's readable.

Comment: How about PlotRange -> {{0.00001, 1}, Automatic}

Comment: Nope, it plots an empty histogram, with x-axis on logarithmic scale over {1,2.5} and no scale on the y-axis. Before the Automatic you suggested the result was opposite (i.e. blank x-axis, logarithmic {1,2.5} y-axis).

Comment: I wonder why you would want to have the vertical axis on a log scale and also have the horizontal axis on a log scale after constructing the histogram.  That would seem to make meaningless the "Probability" option.  I understand that if most of the numbers are squeezed to the left, then the usual histogram is not very informative.  However, using `Histogram[Log10[data], Automatic, "Probability"]` might give you a more informative and interpretable display.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I mostly want the log scale on the x-axis. Preferred to keep my options open concerning the y-axis in case the probability varies overwhelmingly fast. Anyway the solutions suggested before do not work even if I don't impose a scaling function on the y-axis. Your suggestion gives a bit better resolution than the default log scale, however it's harder to interpret in comparison to a regular log scale.

Comment: Lots of log scales are used:  pH, Richter, etc.  Your variable might be better interpreted on a log scale if all values are positive.  Also it depends on what the overall objective is.  For example, are histograms from different datasets to be compared?  But I think for any reasonable interpretation, a histogram (or smoothed histogram) needs to have the area sum to a constant amount for comparison to other distributions or datasets (i.e., no log scale for the vertical axis).

Comment: To state the obvious:  your update is equivalent to `Histogram[Log10[data], Automatic, "Probability"]` except that the horizontal axis is labeled in the original units (rather than in the exponents).  That command actually constructs a histogram with equal bin widths based on `Log10[data]` rather than just changing the scale of the axis.  But the axis is now on a Log10 scale.  So I'd say you've answered your own question.  (But `Show` is not necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `PlotRange` specification is setting the range of the y-axis.  You need to adjust it to set the range of the x-axis.

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.00001, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. It's actually the same as what @Lotus offered. Under the exact same command as you've written (and the aforementioned data) I'm getting a blank histogram with no ticks over the y-axis and a log-scale x-axis over {1,2.5}. Any guesses to what may be wrong?

Comment: Try executing in a new kernel.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. To execute in a new kernel I followed this [link](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12425), still same output.

Comment: You have restarted Mathematica and have a notebook that only has the `data` assignment and the `Histogram` code above and it does not work?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Also tried deleting paclets and restarting the computer. No success yet.